# Materializecss dropdown initialization Error with angular 6

Tags: angular6, materialize

while initializing the dropdown from angular6, it is throwing an error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'tabIndex' of null
at n.value (materialize.min.js:6)
at new n (materialize.min.js:6)
at Function.value (materialize.min.js:6)
at Function.value (materialize.min.js:6)
at NavHeaderComponent.push../src/app/components/headers/nav-header/nav-header.component.ts.NavHeaderComponent.ngOnInit (nav-header.component.ts:24)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9250)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10514)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10476)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11109)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11069)
```

below is the code I used to initialize it,

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    const instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

put this on top:

import * as M from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize';

Answer (score 0):

use *id* selector instead class selector. for example call dropdown like this :

**js:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    const elems = document.querySelectorAll('#dropdownId');
    const instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems);
  }
```